# Scroll up when there are few records in pagination

Tags: angular6

I am using ngb pagination of bootstrap in my angular 6 application, now the situation is that when we have twelve records coming in the from API, the ngb pagination shows first 10 records as we set page size to 10 as below. everything works fine but when user clicks on 2nd page in the pager, it moves the page where there are only two records, but user has to scroll up to see those records. therefore user is requesting that it has to scroll up automatically whenever there are few records as stated in above scenario.

```
 <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="pager.totalCount" [page]="pager.pageNumber" (pageChange)=" getMyOrders($event)"
                  [maxSize]="3" [ellipses]="false" [rotate]="true"></ngb-pagination>
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be some design/CSS which is causing this issue, i tried but not able to replicate the issue that you reported...

relevant **HTML**:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let i of currentList"> {{ i }} </li>
    </ul>

    <ngb-pagination class="d-flex justify-content-center" [collectionSize]="numPages * 10" [(page)]="page" aria-label="Default pagination"
     (pageChange)="loadNext()"> </ngb-pagination>
</div>
```

relevant **TS**:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  page = 1;
  setSize = 10;

  someList = ['item1', 'item2', 'litem', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8', 'item9', 'item10',
    'item11', 'item12', 'item13'];

  numPages = this.someList.length / 10;
  currentList = this.someList.slice(0, 10);

  ngOnInit() {}

  loadNext = () => {
    const pointer = (this.page - 1) * this.setSize;
    const endPointer = pointer + 10;
    this.currentList = this.someList.slice(pointer, endPointer);
  }

}
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-pagination-nun38p?file=src/app/app.component.html)